# Python threads, keylog

Tags: python, многопоточность

**Что должно получится в результате?**

Запускается программа. Считывает все нажатия клавиш, записывая их например в список(пример ниже, но эта часть не так важна, так как я её уже написал, она исправно работает). Но параллельно, например, каждую минуту включалась нужная функция и весь тот результат(список) записывала, скидывала, сохраняла куда угодно, в общем чтобы включалась функция(функционал так же не столь важен). Как мне подсказали - использовать многопоточность.

*пример:*
['enter', 'd', 'h', 'F1', 'capslock', 'y'...]

**Что не выходит?**

Не могу правильно разобраться и структурировать код чтобы работало правильно.

**Какая ошибка?**

После запуска python main.py функция start() - опускается, поток не запускается соответственно функция send_data() которую должен был запустить поток - игнорируется.

**Код?**

```
from threading import Thread
from win32api import LoadKeyboardLayout
import keyboard
import time

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = list()
        keyboard.hook(self.key_logger)
        keyboard.wait()

    def start(self):
        th1 = Thread(target=self.send_data(), args=())
        th1.start()
        time.sleep(4)
        
    def key_logger(self, btn): # функция которая бы сохраняла нажатия в список
        res = btn.name
        print(res)

    def send_data(self): # функция которая бы отсылала нажатия например в файл
        print('i am here') 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    LoadKeyboardLayout('00000409', 1) # устанавливаем англ. язык
    App().start()
```

Очень буду благодарен если поможете с кодом и объяснениями.

P.S. Сори если для кого-то этот вопрос слишком легкий и кажется тупым.

Comment: Можно подробнее вот про это *функция start() - опускается, поток не запускается*? Что значит опускается? Вы проверяли отладчиком? Точно не заходит в функцию `start`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не пользовался модулями, которые Вы используете здесь, однако, исходя из документации, могу предположить следующее:

В конструкторе класса Вы вызываете метод `keyboard.wait()`, который, согласно [документации](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.wait), блокирует выполнение навсегда, если ему не переданы параметры. Таким образом, получаем: в данной строке `App().start()` сначала вызывается конструирующий метод `__init__` класса `App`. Т.к. в этом методе содержится вызов блокирующего метода, выполнение программы блокируется, а значит вызов метода `start()` не происходит, т.к. конструктор ещё не вернул управление и объект до конца не создан.

Решение: убрать блокирующий метод из конструктора.

Далее, хочу ещё отметить, что при передаче в конструктор класса `Thread` функции, которая должна выполняться в потоке, Вы допустили ошибку, поставив скобки после неё. Вот здесь: `th1 = Thread(target=self.send_data(), args=())` после `send_data` скобки не нужны. Когда Вы ставите скобки после имени функции, Вы производите её вызов, а значит аргументу `target` в данном случае будет присвоено то, что вернул Ваш метод `send_data`, а там должен быть сам метод, а не его возвращаемое значение. В Вашем случае метод у Вас вызовется ДО создания потока, а поток не создастся, т.к. не получит в качестве `target` корректного имени функции.

Решение: `th1 = Thread(target=self.send_data, args=())`